# While Scrolling ListView, Listview data should be display under transparent Appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I want to make appear transparent while scrolling listview..I have tried with using stackoverflow coding but looks like this effort is nothing for making what I want to make...

Appear should be convert into transparent and Listview items should be displayed behind transparent appear

here is my basic level code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectIndex = 0;
  bool isAppbarCollapsing = false;
  final ScrollController _homeController = new ScrollController();

  List<String> notelist = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V'
  ];


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initializeController();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _homeController.dispose();
  }

  void _initializeController(){
    _homeController.addListener(() {
      if(_homeController.offset == 0.0 && !_homeController.position.outOfRange){
        //Fully expanded situation
        if(!mounted) return;
        setState(() => isAppbarCollapsing = false);
      }
      if(_homeController.offset >= 9.0 && !_homeController.position.outOfRange){
        //Collapsing situation
        if(!mounted) return;
        setState(()  => isAppbarCollapsing = true);
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transparent Demo'),
          backgroundColor: isAppbarCollapsing ?Colors.transparent:Colors.blue,

      ),
      body: MyBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget MyBody() {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _homeController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: notelist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: (){
                       },
                        title: Text(notelist[index]),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          child: Text(notelist[index][0],style:
                          TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),),
                        ),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: By transparent what do you mean ? Can you add an image for the result that you are expecting please

Comment: I can't add image as I am not allowed..but willl try later..What I Want is that..If I scroll listview..appbar should be converted into transparent so that listview items can be seen under transparent appear....as same as we see in whatsapp while opening media image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extendBodyBehindAppBar and set it to true, make elevation 0. Try the code below

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectIndex = 0;
  bool isAppbarCollapsing = false;
  final ScrollController _homeController = new ScrollController();

  List<String> notelist = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I',
    'J',
    'K',
    'L',
    'M',
    'N',
    'O',
    'P',
    'Q',
    'R',
    'S',
    'T',
    'U',
    'V'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initializeController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _homeController.dispose();
  }

  void _initializeController() {
    _homeController.addListener(() {
      if (_homeController.offset == 0.0 &&
          !_homeController.position.outOfRange) {
        //Fully expanded situation
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() => isAppbarCollapsing = false);
      }
      if (_homeController.offset >= 9.0 &&
          !_homeController.position.outOfRange) {
        //Collapsing situation
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() => isAppbarCollapsing = true);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transparent Demo'),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: isAppbarCollapsing ? Colors.transparent : Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: MyBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget MyBody() {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _homeController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: notelist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () {},
                        title: Text(notelist[index]),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          child: Text(
                            notelist[index][0],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted...Thanks Bro...Excellent..Now I will do it more better...Actually I had doubt that My code is not enough to make it..But adding just few properties and its done..Good..Thanks..